# TypeError: NoneType object is not callable on GeoDjango

Tags: python, django, django-models, geodjango

Although I have read many similar articles about `PointField` and `'NoneType' object error`, I can't figure out how this field should be automatically save according to the latitude and longitude variables I received from the user.

Here is my model:

```
    from django.db import models
    from django.contrib.gis.db import models
    from django.contrib.gis.geos import Point
    
    class Firm(models.Model):
        FirmName = models.CharField(max_length=50)
        address = models.CharField(max_length=1000, null=True, blank=True)
        FirmAddress = models.PointField(null=True, blank = True, geography=True, default=Point(0.0, 0.0))
        lat = models.FloatField(null=True, blank=True)
        lng = models.FloatField(null=True, blank=True)
        Logo = models.ImageField(null=True, blank=True)
    
        @property
        def save(self, *args, **kwargs):
            self.FirmAddress = Point(self.lng, self.lat)
            super(Firm, self).save(*args, **kwargs)
```

On the Django shell, I type
`from firm.models import Firm` command first and then
`Firm.objects.create(FirmName="QWERTY", address="temp", lat=24, lng=54, Logo='logo.jpg')` command.
Here is the error I got at the end:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<console>", line 1, in <module>
  File "C:\Users\Deniz\Desktop\PROJECT\fenv\lib\site-packages\django\db\models\manager.py", line 85, in manager_method
    return getattr(self.get_queryset(), name)(*args, **kwargs)
  File "C:\Users\Deniz\Desktop\PROJECT\fenv\lib\site-packages\django\db\models\query.py", line 453, in create
    obj.save(force_insert=True, using=self.db)
TypeError: 'NoneType' object is not callable
```

But when I look at my database, I see that a value of type geography-point has been added to the `FirmAddress` column. When I remove the FirmAddress feature and update the model, I don't get any errors and everything works fine.

The part I'm having trouble understanding is, if FirmAddress data can be added to the database correctly, why am I getting the `'NoneType' object` error? How can I fix this situation? Many thanks.

Comment: remove the `@property` from the `save` method.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Why am I getting the 'NoneType' object error?

Because you defined `save` as a `@property`. As a result if you use `self.save`, it will call the save method, and `self.save` will take as value what the object *returned*, but that is `None`, hence the error.

You thus should remove the `@property` decorator:

```
class Firm(models.Model):
    # …
    
    # no property
    def save(self, *args, **kwargs):
        self.FirmAddress = Point(self.lng, self.lat)
        return super().save(*args, **kwargs)
```